# What is the function of both of the のか's in this sentence

Tags: syntax, questions, nominalization

What is the function of both of the のか's in this sentence?

> 現代の私達にとって古代エジプトが一体どんな関係がある**のか**、突き詰めて言えば考古学というのが一体役に立つ**のか**、というふうに思っている方がいるかもしれません。

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xs-XWk_oQA
0:28

Below is the English translation from this source, but I feel like some of the meaning is simplified:

"Some people may wonder how ancient Egypt is relevant for our lives today."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two phrases are actually separate complete sentences:

> 現代の私達にとって古代エジプトが一体どんな関係があるのか
>   突き詰めて言えば考古学というのが一体役に立つのか

Both of them are being quoted by the following phrase:

> というふうに思っている方がいるかもしれません。

方 in this case is かた, a polite way to say person/people. It is quoting the first two phrases as examples of things people might say.

の at the end of a sentence adds the sense of giving or asking for an explanation. か of course makes it a question, but it can also be used to list possibilities.